# Slow copying of virtual table rtree

Tags: database, sqlite

From the file system the code is copied into an in-memory database.

After some measurement of the copying process the result was that the virtual table needs a lot of time. My assumption is that it has to do with the shadow tables.

First here the results:

```
Attached to database on file system in 7 milliseconds.
Created in-memory table-1 in 2 milliseconds.
Created in-memory table-2 in 2 milliseconds.
Copied table-1 in 2953 milliseconds.
Copied table-2 in 3086 milliseconds.
Create in-memory coordinates table in 4 milliseconds.
Copied coordinates table in 78813 milliseconds.
Detached from database on file system in 12 milliseconds.
Completed time was 84880 milliseconds.
```

The table scheme on the hard disk looks like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE coordinates USING rtree(
            id,
            min_latitude,
            max_latitude,
            min_longitude,
            max_longitude,
            );
```

The copying process looks like this in Java:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.execute("ATTACH '" + databasePath + "' AS fs");
statement.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mCoordinates USING rtree(id, min_latitude, max_latitude, min_longitude, max_longitude)");
statement.execute("INSERT INTO mCoordinates (id, min_latitude, max_latitude, min_longitude, max_longitude) SELECT id, min_latitude, max_latitude, min_longitude, max_longitude FROM fs.coordinates");
```

Here now my question: "Is there a chance to get a better performance"?

Comment: At the moment: sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coordinates; 151122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing 150,000 R-tree entries from scratch just takes some time.

However, if both databases have the same page size, you could just copy the contents of the shadow tables:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM mCoordinates_node;
INSERT INTO mCoordinates_node   SELECT * FROM fs.coordinates_node;
INSERT INTO mCoordinates_parent SELECT * FROM fs.coordinates_parent;
INSERT INTO mCoordinates_rowid  SELECT * FROM fs.coordinates_rowid;
COMMIT;
```